# Error in subquery nested to WHERE SQL Developer

Tags: jquery, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem doing a sub-query to extract data in my tables. They ask me the following:

1. The results must meet several criteria: The sum of the payments must be greater than the sum of all the payments received by the employee who has Rut: 11630572 in the month of August of this year.

Tried to fix it with this code, doing a queries comparison but it throws me all blank, no data:

```
SELECT 
    c.desc_emp_category, e.emp_name || ' '|| e.appaterno_emp || ' '|| apmaterno_emp AS "FULL_NAME",
    p.province_name,  
    TO_CHAR (e.numrut_emp, '99G999G999') || '-' || e.dvrut_emp AS "RUT",
    TO_CHAR (SUBSTR (pa.pa.date_pago, 4,2)) AS "MONTH",
    SUM(pa.monto_to_cancelar) AS MONTHLY_SALES

DESDE
employee_category c 
JOIN
    employee e ON (c.id_categoria_emp) = (e.id_categoria_emp)
JOIN 
    pay_attention pa ON (e.numrut_emp) = (pa.numrut_emp)
JOIN 
    commune co ON (co.cod_comuna) = (e.id_comuna)
JOIN 
    province p ON (p.cod_provincia) = (co.cod_provincia)
GROUP BY
   c.desc_categoria_emp,
   e.emp_name || ' '|| e.appaterno_emp || ' '|| apmaterno_emp, e.g. province_name,
   TO_CHAR (e.numrut_emp, '99G999G999') || '-' || e.dvrut_emp,    
   TO_CHAR (SUBSTR (pa.pay_date, 4,2))
HAVING
    SUM(pa.monto_a_cancelar) > (SELECT SUM(pa.monto_a_cancelar)
                                FROM PAGO_ATENCION pa
                                WHERE EXTRACT (month from pa.date_pago) = EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE -4)
                                  AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM pa.date_pago) = EXTRACT (YEAR FROM SYSDATE))
ORDER BY 
    "RUT", "MONTHLY_SALES";
```

So .. I can't find another way to do what they ask for, equaling the requested month and the current year, a parametric report .. if someone can help me please.

Comment: Ready, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is the portion you are having an issue with -

```
(SELECT sum (pa.monto_a_cancelar)
from PAGO_ATENCION pa
where EXTRACT (month from pa.pa.date_pago) = EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE -4)
AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM pa.pa.date_pago) = EXTRACT (YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
)
```

It looks like you are referencing **pa.pa.date_pago**, I'm thinking it should be **pa.date_pago**

Comment: Hi, thanks  for your answer! I have edited that part of the code but unfortunately it follows the same error... :(